# Error when attempting to recreate WCF service client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

A little background, I have a WCF service that uses jwt tokens as the "password".  Everything works fine until the token expires, ok no problem.  I'm attempting to re-create the service client after obtaining a new token (since the `ClientCredentials.Username.Password` field turns read-only after opening the client).  After long debugging I've gotten to the code so simple it makes no sense why it doesn't work.  Basically I'm creating the client and opening the connection (works great as it always has).  Then, I attempt to close and re-create the service so I can update the password (token).  The weird thing is I get weird errors, even though the exact same code worked literal milliseconds beforehand.  The errors I receive are:

```
The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
```

And when reviewing the WCF trace I also get

```
The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

Which makes no sense because it should be the exact same "algorithm" that's used in the exact same code just lines before.  I'm hoping some WCF angel can come save the day with something I clearly am missing

Sample code snippit

```
var rService = new RServiceReference.RIServiceClient();

//Set the client credentials for the service
rService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
rService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

try
{
    rService.Open(); //This works no problem

    rService.Close();

    //Start a fresh service client, since we need to do this in order to set the password again
    rService = new RServiceReference.RIServiceClient();

    //And update the credentials
    rService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
    rService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

    //Finally attempt to reconnect
    rService.Open(); //THIS  is where it bombs for some reason giving the errors above.

}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```

I can include the app.config info if requested, but considering everything works as expected until I go to recreate the instance I can't think how it would be anything with the config.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you call `rService.Dispose();` after that close call and before you create a new instance.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the configuration file? According to your existing code, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @rene the IServiceClient doesn't have a `Dispose()` function

Comment: @Dingpeng I could post the app.configs.  Though I have good news and bad news.  Good is that if I change the reference to the server the service is running on (instead of my dev machine) it works.  So clearly a configuration issue on my machine.  Will make it tricky to debug but at least the code is correct.

Comment: is rService in the Closed stated when you create the new instance?

Comment: @rene Yep, closes correctly.  I even tried creating a whole new object but still had the same issue.  It seems to be a configuration issue on my particular machine, as the same thing works correctly when I use the main server as the endpoint.  I will likely try to do some more debugging later but am moving on from this right now to keep going forward.